# The best way to discretise a 3D model into a matrix

Tags: 3d, geometry, minecraft, 3d-modelling

I want to take a 3D model that I could make in something like blender, sketchup etc and discretise it into a 3D matrix.

You could say I wanted to "Minecraftise" an arbitrary object. (Except it's for a simulation)

An example: Here's a discretised cylinder with hemi-spherical ends:

[image]

My current idea would be to take a list of vertices that describe the object and see which cells in the matrix they would occupy and then mark it as occupied by the object.

1) Is this a good approach?

2) If so what's the easiest model format to work with to accomplish this task, is there some standard good quality library?

Thanks

Comment: Your main problem will be that meshes are not solid... They are just made out of faces and edges, but in the inside they are hollow. So checking wether your voxel is "inside" the mesh is gonna be hard, since there is not really an "inside".

Comment: Is there no file format where I could save it as being "filled in"?

Comment: I don't know. But that's a rather hard mathematical problem. Properly defining the inside of a randomly shaped object is really hard to do, mathematically, I guess.

Comment: +1 for interesting problem. I do not know of any format that support this but you will be better of with your own in binary representation to speed up load times. also RLE compression is a good idea to implement.

Comment: @RNs_Ghost I added a link to related QA which might interests you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **create render engine** for your model directly to 3D matrix not on screen (**Volume rendering**)

   either use own soft render or **OpenGL + GLSL** or whatever...
2. **clear matrix**

   with empty color
3. **render your model to matrix**

   no `CULL_FACE` removal, no `Z buffer` and **no PERSPECTIVE projection !!!**
4. **fill inside of mesh**

   cast ray for each row of the matrix and set as filled all those there are inside. At start of ray voxels are outside and when you hit any filled voxel then it is inside from that point. When you hit any filled voxel again then it is outside from that point and so on ...

**In software render the write pixel is like this:**

```
DWORD scr[ys][xs],DWORD zed[ys][xs]; // screen and Z buffers xs,ys is resolution

void setpixel(DWORD x,DWORD y,DWORD z,DWORD color) // x,y,z, are already projected
 {
 if ((x>=0)&&(x<xs)) // cut off out of screen pixels
  if ((y>=0)&&(y<ys))
   if (z<=zed[y][x]) // test Z buffer
    scr[y][x]=color; // write color to pixel
 }
```

So just change it to this:

```
DWORD vox[zs][ys][xs]; // voxel buffer (your 3D matrix)

void setpixel(DWORD x,DWORD y,DWORD z,DWORD color) // x,y,z, are already projected
 {
 if ((x>=0)&&(x<xs)) // cut off out of volume pixels
  if ((y>=0)&&(y<ys))
   if ((z>=0)&&(z<zs))
    vox[z][y][x]=color; // write color to voxel
 }
```

In **OpenGL** you can draw to array of textures or use 3D texture ... I do not use **DirectX** but I think it can be achieved there also. Here my **GLSL** example for this:

- [GLSL voxel back ray-tracer using `GL_TEXTURE_3D`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214)